sudo passwordless in ssh session not working
In RHEL7, I have the same local users on all machines within my cloud tenancy. That local user is configured in sudoers to be able to:

run all commands,
run sudo commands without password

EDIT: ssh passwordless is set up on all machines for that local user.
When that user runs any sudo command locally on any machine, it works as expected (no prompt for password). However, when running a sudo command as part of ssh session as that local user, it is prompted for password such as:
ssh -q -t -t <REMOTE_HOST> 'sudo ps'
We trust you have received the usual lecture from the local System
Administrator. It usually boils down to these three things:
    #1) Respect the privacy of others.
    #2) Think before you type.
    #3) With great power comes great responsibility.
Password:

What can be causing this behavior with ssh?

Not sure if I understand. You want to login without using ssh-copy-id? You are aware of the security implications of all this setup?

If you have not set up your SSH authorized keys or any small detail about the permissions of those files, you will be prompted for a password when making an ssh connection to that host.   Have you confirmed that you can make a passwordless ssh command, if you issue ps instead of sudo ps?
You may also want to set the
!requiretty  Defaults option in your /etc/sudoers file, for either a particular user or all users.
Here's a snippet of how to set it for a user named username1.
username1    ALL=(ALL:ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL
Defaults:username1 !requiretty


Apologize for the confusion. SSH passwordless is set up on all machines for that local user. The password prompt is for the SUDO command and password prompting happens ONLY if sudo command is run as part of ssh session. When that sudo command is run locally on the remote machine, there is no prompt for password.

I just noticed you said RHEL7, few can support that system. You really need to migrate off RHEL7.  The only plausible explanation I have for this problem is an ssh related configuration that is trashing environment variables or ttys.  You need to test with SSH and sudo not requiring ttys to eliminate that possibility.

I tried your suggestion, did not work. Also "-t -t" is supposed to force pseudo-terminal allocation. Is there any possibility that there is conflict with the LDAP authentication scheme vs local account?

@LouLee Diffrent configurations can screw up pty/tty allocations, regardless of specifying it via command line option, that is why the suggestion.  This is your environment, this is not a publicly quantifiable environment,  all we can do is guess at what possible misconfiguration you have.

@LouLee
LDAP itself is just a directory, it is not itself a domain.  That means systems engineers/administrations can use it to control their system configurations, but it's something they would have to setup, and you'd have to know about.  Can you confirm that your sudoers file is even applicable?  Can you create a whole new account, add it to the sudoers file NOPASSWD:ALL, and confirm that config change was impactful?  Typically sudoers files are synchronized by a directory, and your sudoers changes would end up clobbered, or sudoers are centralized and your changes would be ignored.

After some further digging, it appears that the user's profile is different when running commands in ssh session as compared to running that same commandly interactively on the remote machine.
